# Htaccess RewriteCond Expr not executing

Tags: apache, .htaccess, amazon-lightsail

Per [Amazon's Lightsail Troubleshooting](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lightsail-load-balancer-troubleshoot/) I'm trying to update my htaccess to ignore a specific file during the HTTPS redirecting. However, it doesn't seem to be ignoring it.

What I want to happen is, if the user visits http://example.com/health-checker.html they aren't redirected to the HTTPs version. However, if they visit anything else they are redirected to the HTTPs version.

When I use the below code, they are still directed to the HTTPS version. To test if it was a browser caching issue, I used a different file name and still same problem.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond expr "! %{REQUEST_URI} -strmatch '*health-checker.html'"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Please note that I'm hard coding my domain name intentionally due to dealing with multiple domain names.

Your assistance is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need `expr` here, you can just use regular `RewriteCond` with negation like this:

```sh
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/health-checker\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you but for some reason that still isn't working. I even tested it out with a different HTML file to verify the browser isn't caching it.

Comment: Can you try my updated rule. If that doesn't work then I suggest you provide your full .htaccess in question